# Cannot Download BootCamp Support Driver on Windows 10 because of the Unsuitable Model

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I currently downloaded Windows 10 on Mac, but it doesn't allow me to download the Boot Camp Support Software. I also tried to format Boot Camp Driver and reinstall, same result. So, I downloaded the latest support software from Apple's official website, but when I run the file, it said "this version of Boot Camp doesn't match with your device's model" or something like that. I'm using MacBook Air 2017. What version of BootCamp Software should I download?

Comment: What is "it" when you state "it doesn't allow me to download the Boot Camp Support Software"? What is "format" mean when you state "format Boot Camp Driver"? What is the URL for the website when you state "downloaded the latest support software from Apple's official website"?

Answer (score 0):

The Boot Camp Assistant can be use to download a version of the Boot Camp Software for your model Mac. Look for `Download Windows Support Software` under `Action` on the menu bar. You should run this application from the most recent version of macOS that your Mac can currently boot to. To insure you get the most recent version of the Boot Camp Support Software available for your Mac, you should install and boot to the latest version of macOS that is compatible with your Mac. In your case, this would be Monterey.

---

The only link that I know of, that can download the Windows Support Software for your model Mac directly from Apple, is [this one](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/62/58/041-98143-A_HN8B941A1T/nknv1gt3xcgylggwc11kl5e0j4296tjfo1/BootCampESD.pkg). Note: When unpacking the download, you may need to look in the `/Library/Application Support/BootCamp` folder.